# Redirect rules for nginx .conf file

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a list of redirect rules in my .conf file for our site  (about 10k lines of redirect rules)

They are a mixture of rules styles

```
rewrite ^(.*)/p-100.aspx(.*)$ https:page A
```

and

```
if ($query_string ~ "BrandID=123"){ rewrite .*$ page B? redirect; }
```

The rewrite rules are listed first and the "if" rules are later on, but if the url is "mysite/p-100.aspx?BrandID=123"  it seems the "If redirect" rule over rides the "rewrite" rule.

Can I have it so that rewrite rules take priority? over the if statements?

please note I have 1000's of rewite rules and 1000s of "If" rules

Thanks

edit:  adding a bigger chuck of code as requested.

```
rewrite ^(.*)/b-113.aspx(.*)$ https:page1.hmtl permanent;
rewrite ^(.*)/b-114.aspx(.*)$ https:page2.hmtl permanent;
rewrite ^(.*)/b-115.aspx(.*)$ https:page3.hmtl permanent;
rewrite ^(.*)/b-116.aspx(.*)$ https:page4.hmtl permanent;
rewrite ^(.*)/b-117.aspx(.*)$ https:page5.hmtl permanent;
rewrite ^(.*)/b-118.aspx(.*)$ https:page6.hmtl permanent;
rewrite ^(.*)/b-119.aspx(.*)$ https:page5.hmtl permanent;
rewrite ^(.*)/b-120.aspx(.*)$ https:page6.hmtl permanent;
rewrite ^(.*)/b-121.aspx(.*)$ https:page7.hmtl permanent;
rewrite ^(.*)/b-122.aspx(.*)$ https:page8.hmtl permanent;

if ($query_string ~ "BrandID=122"){ rewrite .*$ pageA.hmtl? redirect; }
if ($query_string ~ "BrandID=121"){ rewrite .*$ pageB.hmtl? redirect; }
if ($query_string ~ "BrandID=120"){ rewrite .*$ pageC.hmtl? redirect; }
if ($query_string ~ "BrandID=119"){ rewrite .*$ pageD.hmtl? redirect; }
if ($query_string ~ "BrandID=118"){ rewrite .*$ pageE.hmtl? redirect; }
if ($query_string ~ "BrandID=117"){ rewrite .*$ pageF.hmtl? redirect; }
if ($query_string ~ "BrandID=116"){ rewrite .*$ pageG.hmtl? redirect; }
if ($query_string ~ "BrandID=115"){ rewrite .*$ pageI.hmtl? redirect; }
if ($query_string ~ "BrandID=114"){ rewrite .*$ pageJ.hmtl? redirect; }
```

Note that the page.html are not the real urls and are all unique urls

Comment: It seems like you have O(n) rules which causes maintenance problem. The only way to help is that you share a big chunk of configuration and let us find a communality followed by optimisation to shrink down to O(LogN) or even O(1)

Comment: What do you mean by "O(n) rules"?  I should have explained these are direct rules due to a website platform migration.  I'll update the question with a bigger chunk, but it literately 1000s of rewrite lines followed by 100s of "if" rules

Comment: number or conditions and rewrites is directly proportional to the number of lines of code